# Getting a string from Python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a List object like this `['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3 tag3', ...]`

How I can skip `[`, `]`, `'` characters and get a string `"tag1, tag2, tag3 tag3, ..."`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have a list of strings you could do:

```
>>> lst = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3 tag3']
>>> ', '.join(lst)
'tag1, tag2, tag3 tag3'
```

Note: you do not **remove characters** `[`, `]`, `'`. You're concatenating elements of a list into a string. Original list will remain untouched. These characters serve for representing relevant types in python: lists and string, specifically.

Comment: @Anry: again, representation of string is not the same as content of the string. the output that I posted **doesn't have** any quotes inside it. It is only for you to see that it is a string.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way, for your example, would be to take the substring that excludes the first and last character.

```
myStr = myStr[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> import re
>>> s = "[test, test2]"
>>> s = re.sub("\[|\]", "", s)
>>> s
'test, test2'
```

Comment: misinterpreted the question anyway

Answer (score 0):

If the '[' and ']' will always be at the front and end of the string, you can use the string strip function.

```
s = '[tag1, tag2, tag3]'
s.strip('[]')
```

This should remove the brackets.